# Function environment

Tags: r, function

I'm reading [Hands-on Programing with R](https://www.amazon.com.br/Hands-Programming-Write-Functions-Simulations-ebook/dp/B00LPUIB8C?tag=goog0ef-20&smid=A18CNA8NWQSYHH&ascsubtag=58532425-1d4e-4b88-91d7-4143ef185cdd) and he creates the following function in an exemple:

```
setup <- function(deck){
      DECK <- deck

      DEAL <- function(){
            card <- deck[1,]
            assign("deck",deck[-1,],envir = parent.env(environment()))
            card
      }

      SHUFFLE <- function(){
              random <- sample(1:52,52)
              assign("deck",DECK[random,],envir = parent.env(environment()))
      }
      list(deal=DEAL, shuffle=SHUFFLE)
}

cards <- setup(deck)
deal <- cards$deal
shuffle <- cards$shuffle
```

Where deck is [here](https://gist.github.com/garrettgman/9629323).

When I first call `deal` the environment that is shown is `<environment: 0x9eea314>`. Then I start to deal with the function `deal()` and I figure out that if I call `setup(deck)` again the deal function will be reset. I do that, the environment of `deal` was change to `<environment: 0xad77a60>` but for my surprising when I deal with `deal()` continued from where it had stopped. I call `deal` and I saw that in fact the environment was not change.

What is happening? When I first setup the deal function no matters how many times I call `setup(deck)`it will not changes or I'm creating others functions deal in a different environment that the scoping rule doesn't reach?

Comment: This code is unusual for R, as it doesn't really fit into R's usual OOP frameworks. (It look suspiciously like code translated to R from a more OOP-focused language.) If you really need to write code like this, [R6](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R6/vignettes/Introduction.html) provides a nice infrastructure, but frankly unless you're developing packages it's not normally necessary, as there are more transparent, idiomatic ways to write equivalent code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that the "deck" you want to be looking at is inside the `cards`-object. After `shuffle()` we can see this behavior:

```
> deal()
   face  suit value
17  ten clubs    10
> str(deck)
'data.frame':   52 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ face : Factor w/ 13 levels "ace","eight",..: 6 8 5 11 7 2 9 10 3 4 ...
 $ suit : Factor w/ 4 levels "clubs","diamonds",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ value: int  13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 ...
```

So I do see your puzzlement. I, like you, was expecting to see 51 cards in the deck, and I was expecting to have a random ordering of the card values and suits (which we don't see either), but let's continue ...

```
> deal()
    face     suit value
37 three diamonds     3
> deal()
   face  suit value
23 four clubs     4
> str(cards)
```

Now let's try to find the "real" `deck`-object that is being manipulated by the `shuffle` and `deal` functions, and it's clearly not the same as the `deck` object that remains unchanged in the `globalenv()`. R functions are actually closures, which are a combination of code and an enclosing environment. With that in mind, let's inspect `cards`:

```
> str(cards)
List of 2
 $ deal   :function ()  
  ..- attr(*, "srcref")=Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 4 15 8 7 15 7 4 8
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x7f84081d3780> 
 $ shuffle:function ()  
  ..- attr(*, "srcref")=Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 10 18 13 7 18 7 10 13
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x7f84081d3780>
```

Now inspect the *environment* of the first of the functions inside `cards`:

```
> ls(env=environment(cards[[1]]))
[1] "DEAL"    "deck"    "DECK"    "SHUFFLE"
```

And now take a look at the value of "deck" inside that environment:

```
str(environment(cards[[1]])$deck)
'data.frame':   49 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ face : Factor w/ 13 levels "ace","eight",..: 4 1 13 7 11 13 8 2 2 3 ...
 $ suit : Factor w/ 4 levels "clubs","diamonds",..: 4 1 4 1 3 3 4 3 4 1 ...
 $ value: int  4 1 2 9 10 2 12 8 8 5 ...
```

So I think we have found the actual "deck"-object that we should be looking at (since it has both the correct number and random ordering), and it's not the one that's still (unchanged) in the `globalenv()`. Furthermore, the environments of those two functions are shared:

```
 environment(cards[[2]])
#<environment: 0x7f84081702a8>
 environment(cards[[1]])
#<environment: 0x7f84081702a8>
```

... however, I think there might be a problem with game "semantics" if `shuffle` were performed accidentally during a game:

```
> shuffle()
> str(environment(cards[[2]])$deck)
'data.frame':   52 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ face : Factor w/ 13 levels "ace","eight",..: 11 9 2 7 8 1 7 3 5 13 ...
 $ suit : Factor w/ 4 levels "clubs","diamonds",..: 2 3 4 4 2 4 3 4 3 3 ...
 $ value: int  10 7 8 9 12 1 9 5 11 2 ...
```